# Cannot concatenate string columns

Tags: sql-server

I'd like to concatenate three columns - street, street number and city to one column "adress". The strange thing is that I cannot do it for some reason.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
SELECT      street,
            street_num,
            city,
            isnull(street,'') + '' + isnull(street_num,'') + '' + isnull(city,'') AS tst1, --doesnt work
            concat(isnull(street,''),' ',isnull(street_num,''), ' ', isnull(city,'')) AS tst2, --doesnt work
            (street_num + ' ' + street) AS tst3, --does work
            (street_num + ' ' + city) AS tst4, --does work
            (city + ' ' + street) AS tst5 --doesnt work
FROM        [DB].[dbo].[adresses]
```

Note that `+` or `concat` doesnt work, it only shows the first column, street in these cases. However, if I start with street number and add street or city, it does work. But if I try to add third column, it is not shown.

If it helps, the table was pulled from Oracle by OPENQUERY and the table structure is as follows:

```
street VARCHAR(100), null
street_num VARCHAR(50), null
city VARCHAR(100), null
```

I am on MSSQL 2014.

**EDIT**

As asked in the comments, i cant show the data as I am dealing with addresses of our customers. Below are two dummy records plus expected result (adress) as example:

```
street            | street_num | city   | adress
--------------------------------------------------------------------
avenida pino alto | 45         | avila  | avenida pino alto 45 avila  
rue de abaixo     | 86         | madrid | rue de abaixo 86 madrid
```

Furthermore, If i copy the records and do something like this, it works of course.

```
SELECT 'avenida pino alto' + ' ' + '45' + ' ' + 'avila'
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Comment: Its addresses of our clients, so I cant :(.

Comment: you could extract some of them (two rows) and change manually some values...  Apparently your query is correct (as far as I know)

Comment: @HonzaB:please paste some dummy sample data and expected rsult

Comment: try 
`isnull(CAST(street as varchar) ,'')+' '+isnull(CAST(street_num as varchar) ,'')+' '+isnull(CAST(cityas varchar) ,'')`

Comment: @NikhilGoud doesnt work, still shows only the first column, street in this case.

Comment: You wrote that `(street_num + ' ' + street)` work. Does `(street + ' ' + street_num)` also work? If not, you seem to have some garbage in the street column.

Comment: @user1429080 no, it shows only street.

Comment: @HonzaB Are you saying that the only first column is showing even when the other two columns are `NOT NULL`

Comment: @NikhilGoud yes, thats why I am so confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, it seems that your `street` column contains some char/data that causes problems.

I have no idea what it could be, but you can try to find out like this:

```
select top 10
    street,
    len(street) as streetCharLen,
    cast(street as varbinary(500)) as streetBytes
from [DB].[dbo].[adresses]
```

Then compare what the different columns tell you.

Here's a quick sample:

```
declare @t table (
    id int,
    thestring varchar(50)
)

insert into @t values (1, 'test')

select thestring,
    len(thestring) as slen,
    cast(thestring as varbinary(100)) as sbytes
from @t
```

If in this sample, the `slen` is not 4, or the `sbytes` contains something that does not map back to one of the characters that I see when selecting, then something is wrong with the string.

Comment: All right, so there were some funny addresses. But that actually led me back to Oracle, where were some strange things happening with these columns. Once I cleaned it, it works like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use convert(varchar,[exp]):

```
SELECT      street,
            street_num,
            city,
            isnull(convert(varchar,street),'') + '' + isnull(convert(varchar,street_num),'') + '' + isnull(convert(varchar,city),'') AS tst1

FROM        [DB].[dbo].[adresses]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows.

```
    select isnull((convert varchar(250),street),'')+isnull((convert varchar(250),[street number]),'')+
    isnull((convert varchar(250),[city]),'') as 'Adress'
    from .......(your query)
```